# Does 'Iterable' interface look redundant in java?

Tags: java, iterator

By this below definition(pre 1.8) of `Iterable`,

```
package java.lang;

import java.util.Iterator;


public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

I would say that, `Iterable` is dependent on `Iterator` interface as shown below,

```
package java.util;

public interface Iterator<E> {

    boolean hasNext();


    E next();


    default void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }

}
```

Standard recommendation is that, any implementation that implements `Iterable` interface becomes iterable.

But syntactically, `MyClass`can implement interface `Iterator` and enable the implementation `MyClass` as *iterable* without explicitly mentioning  `class MyClass **implements Iterable**{}`, **by adding** `Iterator<T> iterator();` behavior in `Iterator` interface instead of  `Iterable` interface. This would have simplified presenting only one interface(`Iterator`). `Iterator` can hold all the responsibilities that `Iterable` does.

So, What is the rational behind adding `Iterator<T> iterator();` behavior in `Iterable`(redundant) interface instead of `Iterator` interface?

I am not clear with the purpose of introducing `Iterable` interface.

Please help me understand.

*For me, this is not a duplicate question because this is an [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290563/does-iterable-interface-look-redundant-in-java#comment601614_290564) which talks about violation of SRP.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between iterable and enumerable?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/216988/is-there-a-difference-between-iterable-and-enumerable)

Comment: For me, this is not duplicate question, below answer gives exact reason: *Being an iterator (keeping track of the act of iterating over elements), and being able to build new iterators are two different responsibilities* as mentioned below. None of the previous questions answered this exact reason.

Comment: @KonradMorawski one can argue that question boils down to matters of [tag:single-responsibility] and as such, is also a duplicate of [What is the real responsibility of a class?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/220230/31260) :)

Comment: @gnat i might have pasted a wrong link, i can't remember. anyway, this question is actually much more similar to 2 questions posted on StackOverflow - see the links in my answer. but since SO is technically another site, the input form wouldn't let me submit a link to neither of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iterator` is stateful, `Iterable` is stateless.

`Iterator` knows where it is at the moment, but `Iterable` shouldn't, because it can be iterated by two (or more) independent "actors".

Basically `Iterable` is able to provide anyone with a brand new `Iterator` on demand.

It looks like this question keeps on coming up, although mostly on StackOverflow not here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863182/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-and-iterable-and-how-to-use-them

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839178/why-is-javas-iterator-not-an-iterable

Comment: What is the advantage of introducing `Iterable` and making it stateless?  what is the disadvantage in making `iterator()` method sit in `Iterator` interface? As said: *`Iterable` implies that one may obtain an iterator from an object to traverse over its elements*, this responsibility can be hold by `Iterator`

Comment: @overexchange you don't want your iterable `MyClass` instance to know that it's being iterated by someone right now, and to keep track of it - to know that this someone is on the 5th element at the moment ;) For one, because it would make difficult for someone else to iterate over its elements at the same time. As for squashing `Iterable` and `Iterator` into one interface, it would violate Single Responsibility Principle. Being an iterator (keeping track of the act of iterating over elements), and being able to build new iterators are two different responsibilities.

Comment: @overexchange and you wouldn't want your `MyClass` to be its own iterator, for the reasons explained above - but if `Iterable` and `Iterator` were combined in one interface, you could not avoid it.

Comment: to be its own iterator? I would not try mentioning `class Myclass implements Iterator{}` instead the private inner class would implement `Iterator`. I agree with your point that single interface violates SRP.

Comment: @overexchange ok I see - but if you only had `Iterator` as an inner class, how would the outer world know that it can iterate over `MyClass` in a `for ... in` loop? Making it `Iterable` says that explicitly and it seems like the cleanest possible way

Comment: Knowing to the outer world is not a severe issue. **Because**, Does the outer world know that java arrays are *Cloneable* & *Serializable* by using  some syntax except reading java documentation? you dont have syntactic proof for it, because array types are not visible.I feel SRP is strong reason for this division, and `Iterable` sits in `java.lang` and `Iterator` sits in `java.util`.

Comment: @overexchange correct, but `Serializable` does nothing, it's a marker interface. `Iterable ` is more like `Parcelable` in that you're actually supposed to flesh some implementation out. You can delegate iteration to a child class (eg. a collection you enwrap) just by returning its iterator as your own. And if Java ever got reified generics (like C#), `MyClass` could simultaneously support `Iterable<Integer>` and `Iterable<String>`, and you could iterate it as an integer or string sequence alike. Thanks for accepting my answer